# Elasticsearch : _tasks is not giving msearch taskid everytime

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-dsl

I want to cancel msearch running query. I am running this query to get task id of msearch query:

**curl -XGET "localhost:9200/_tasks?actions=*search&detailed&pretty"**

When I run this query, Sometimes I am able to get taskid for msearch in the response by running above query but most of the time I am not getting taskid.

why is it happening ??

Thanks

**Note: msearch request is cancellable(=true)**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/steuY.png)

Comment: Can you share the response you get in both cases?

Comment: check I have added an image

Comment: Well the reason might simply be that your `_msearch` query has already finished don't you think?

Comment: well, I think this can be one reason. but when I hit _msearch request, I am observing it is still pending.